# Making E-mail as primary key in readbeans php

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

How can I make email field as unique and primary key in `redbeans php` ?

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Googled this issue for couple of hours but I din't got any working answer..

Comment: nothing is there in the documentation either...!!

Comment: Rather than make the email a primary key, which i am not sure is a good idea anyway, I would have the email as a property and put a unique index on it. Now, it can be used in queries efficiently, will trigger errors if duplicate inserted. Also, if it changes then you do not lose all the relationships it already has to other tables. I think this is a win.

Comment: Very true Ryan Vincent. .. Thanks for your help....